# Critical editions

Tags: texshop

I use TexShop with the XeLateX typesetting. I've become fairly well versed in its ways. I cannot, however, find the programming necessary to make a critical edition, by which I mean the ability to have many layers of footnotes on a single page, e.g.:

http://www.djdekker.net/ledmac/sample-edition2.pdf

Does anyone know how to do this sort of document in TexShop?

Any help appreciated,
Jonathan Edelmann

Comment: Welcome! Your editor is irrelevant. You just follow the instructions in the manual for the software you decide to use. However, you should use https://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac which supersedes `ledmac`.

Comment: One simple way to get something like this (which I doubt is desirable): `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Abc.\footnote{def}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Xyz.\footnote{uvw}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

This is a funny question, because for us, the folks who more or less live in this forum, the difference between an editor and the TeX-software is obvious. The editor is a software to produce the *.tex file and maybe start compilation. But TeXShop and other editors don't include the machinery to compile a PDF. To this end a LaTeX installation is needed.

Any larger document (the *.tex file) needs a documentclass and packages, which are loaded with the command `\usepackage{packagename}`. Packages provide commands, environments and whatever which you can use in your *.tex file. From the *.tex file the PDF is produced by the mentioned machinery.

There are many packages. Have a look at ctan.org. If you need sophisticated footnotes, have a look at the packages bigfoot or manyfoot. Probably you get the manual by typing »texdoc packagename« in a terminal.

To start a critical edition have a look at e.g. reledmac. The name isn't connected to the computer called »iMac«, but to an old package edmac, years ago.

However, a critical edition usually might take a long time. Get a real introduction for LaTeX, will save you a lot of time.